# OpenGL passthrough shader skipping pixels when copying mipmaps

Tags: opengl, shader, mipmaps

I am trying to copy a texture level from one texture to another, using a simple passthrough shader:

```
#version 330 core
in  vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D scene;
uniform int level;

void main()
{             
    FragColor   = textureLod(scene, TexCoord, level);
}
```

I render an image to an FBO, generate mipmaps, then copy that FBO to another FBO, layer by layer, then render one of those layers to the default framebuffer, always using the most basic passthrough shader.  The copying is performed with the following data:

```
float quadVertices[] = {
    //   positions        texture Coords
    //----------------    -----------
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

This works well when copying levels 0 and 1:

[image]

I can copy layer 2 from one FBO straight to the default framebuffer, and it seems to look fine.

[image]

But for some reason, when copying to another FrameBuffer first, then to the default framebuffer, something looks wrong:

[image]

All of these copies use the same passthrough shader. How can the shader be working in some cases, but not others?

My filters are set to GL_LINEAR and GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR. I am getting no OpenGL Errors reported at all.

Comment: Looks like it might be a filtering issue. I supposed you render a viewport-filling triangle or quad to perform the copy? How exactly do you construct that quad?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - Yes, a pair of triangles. All of the FBO to FBO renders are performed with the same code. The clearly work in some cases, but not in others.  What do you mean by a 'filtering' issue? To me this looks like some kind of aliasing that I have never seen before,  I'm struggling to think what kind of process is causing this.

Comment: And how exactly do you construct these two triangles, i.e., what vertex and what texture coordinates do they have?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - Added to the question.  If I had to guess a sequence of steps to replicate that effect, I would probably do something like a small rotation, followed by resizing down with GL_NEAREST, then generate mip maps, then take the next mip map down, and linearly scale it up.  I'm pretty sure that isn't happening though.

Comment: Wait, do you rotate your quad? Or at the lines in the texture which you want to downfilter not horizontal/vertical? If so, I believe the first picture you posted is the result of the first downfiltering!? If so, could you also post the actual input texture?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - Oops, sorry, I got myself confused and forgot to mention the rotation. No, the quad isn't rotated, it's the rendering of the original lines that's rotated.

Comment: It is totally unclear what the GL states for your copying operations actually are. What about framebuffer and viewport sizes, what about blending, and what is the actual result you are expecting in a scenario with repeated bilinear filtering?